# Need Help Understanding Debug Log Errors

Tags: plugins, errors, debug

I have these errors in my debug.log and I'm at a loss as to how to go about fixing them. I believe they are the culprit behind one of my plugins automatically logging me out.

```
[15-Jun-2018 14:45:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant 
AUTH_COOKIE - assumed 'AUTH_COOKIE' in /home/powers52/public_html/wp- 
includes/pluggable.php on line 769

[15-Jun-2018 14:45:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant 
LOGGED_IN_COOKIE - assumed 'LOGGED_IN_COOKIE' in 
/home/powers52/public_html/wp-includes/user.php on line 340

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at /home/powers52/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php:769)  
in /home/powers52/public_html/wp-content/plugins/WP-Filebase- 
master/classes/Download.php on line 561
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `WP Filebase` plugin and see if the problem is resolved?

Comment: Yes I have. Unfortunately no change.